# Getting all the associated tags for every item after a filterby(tag)

Tags: cakephp

I have the typical association HABTM Item <-> Tag

If i get all the Items with tag= "test" doing this:

```
$items = $this->Item->Tag->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Tag.name'=>$tag)));
```

The $items array shows correctly the [Items] array containing the Items associated with the tag, but 
How can i get also all the Tags for every item, so I can show after the item and all his tags ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Seems like Cake didn't like the idea. You can hack it by calling the association a little differently:

> ```
> $this->Item->bindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
>         'BlahTag'=>array(
>             'className' => 'Tag',
>             'joinTable' => 'items_tags',
>             'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
>             'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
>             'unique' => true,
>         )
>     )),false);
>   $this->Item->BlahTag->bindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
>         'Item'=>array(
>             'className' => 'Item',
>             'joinTable' => 'items_tags',
>             'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
>             'associationForeignKey' => 'item_id',
>             'unique' => true,
>         )
>     )),false);
> ```

```
 $items = $this->Item->BlahTag->find('all', array(
   'contain'=>array('Item'=>array('BlahTag')),
   'conditions'=>array('BlahTag.name'=>$tag)
));
```

Comment: Nop. I've tested it this way and it returns the items but no tags inside items. Tried to attach de behavior both statically and dynamically.

Comment: Yes ! this is the way to do it. Thank you.